# After popview method called,the scrollview stops work

Tags: ios, popviewcontroller

I have navigation container with A, B views in it.

When A first entry stack, I am able to roll the view because I set the scrollview widget in A view. When I roll to the bottom of A view, B view instance will be created and entry the stack (by navigate push).

But there is a problem when I popview to A view, the scrollview is unable to move.

I have tried much, such as:

```
viewWillAppear { 
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

I know only this method will be called when popview from B view.

Answer (score 0):

For scroll view to function, contentSize must be set properly. It is the entire area that should be shown to user but because of small screen size cannot be viewed all in one shot. Please ensure when you come back from view B to view A, scroll view is set with correct frame and contentSize.

Comment: Of course ,when I in A view,that's work.A view's height is 667 while scrollView's hight is 670.I don't adjust its height all the time.

Comment: Thanks your answer in patient.I just can't find the question where it is .